# Get native resolution of video game screenshot

Tags: python, image-processing, resolution

I'm trying to make some sort of "pixel count" program that can detect the native resolution of a screenshot taken in a game.

I have tried this using Python by doing the following:

```
# importing the module 
import PIL 
from PIL import Image 
  
# loading the image 
img = PIL.Image.open("filename.jpg") 
  
# fetching the dimensions 
wid, hgt = img.size 
  
# displaying the dimensions 
print(str(wid) + "x" + str(hgt))
```

Except the problem with this, is that it just gets the resolution of the file itself.

Which is not what I'm trying to achieve.

For reference, I've got a screenshot of Destiny 2 from Google Stadia, and the resolution of the game itself is 1080p, but the game is streamed at 4k.

I have found a way to do this by hand, but it is pretty tedious, so I'm trying to automate it.

If anyone has an idea how to do this, I'd love to hear it :)

Here are 2 screenshots showing my current manual method:
[This image shows a 4k screenshot of a confirmed 1080p game.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jo5Df.png)
[This image shows a 4k screenshot of a confirmed native 4k game.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jNESE.png)

Comment: An image is just an image. It doesn't "know" where it came from, that it's a screenshot of a game, or what resolution the game was running at. Unless the game somehow bakes in some meta-data that corresponds to in-game resolution, all you can ever get from an image is its own resolution.That being said, aren't the dimensions of an in-game screenshot usually identical to the resolution the game happened to be set to? Also, why don't you at least describe your tedious solution in terms of pseudo-code?

Comment: FYI `from PIL import Image` is unnecessary and unused.

Comment: Unfortunately the screenshot is not the same as the game resolution, like what I said with my example, Destiny 2 is rendered at 1080p but streamed at 4k. and then Google  adds "upscaling" over it, to make straight lines look "better".
I currently do: I look for a straight line that isn't 90, 45 or 180 degrees, so it doesn't get hit by the upscaling. then I take a sample of 30 pixels and count the amount of "steps" it has in that line. I then divide the amount of steps by the 30 pixels and that outcome times 2160p (4k).

Destiny example: 15 steps in 30 pixels (15/30)*2160=1080p

Comment: Maybe consider adding 2 screenshots at resolutions you know (and identify) and also showing your manual method on one of them...

Comment: I have added 2 screenshots of the method I'm using.